# How to generate .apk file from index.android.bundle?

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I followed this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2943

```
$ cd your_project_dir
$ npm start  # start the packager if not started already
$ curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android?dev=false" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

And successfully generated a `index.android.bundle` file. But weird, there's nothing out there that explains how to turn that into a **release** `.apk` file.

**EDIT:**

I did:

```
$ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

But `android/app/src/main/res/` only has a manifest file and the app's icon. No `.apk` file.

Comment: Are you trying to get a release or a debug apk ?

Comment: @G.Hamaide A release apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow these steps found on the [RN official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content) to get a release apk. You can then find it there : `android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk`

Basically you need to :

> 1. Generate a signing key
> 2. Set up gradle variables
> 3. Add signing config to your app's grade config
> 4. Generate the release APK